# How do I install JavaFx 2.0 on my mac?

Tags: macos, installation, java, javafx

I need to use JavaFx on my macbook pro. Im using netbeans 7.1.

Currently when i compile my javafx program that I created on windows it gives me this error.

The J2SE Platform is not correctly set up.
 Your active platform is: Default_JavaFX_Platform, but the corresponding property "platforms.Default_JavaFX_Platform.home" is not found in the project's properties files. 
 Either open the project in the IDE and setup the Platform with the same name or add it manually.
 For example like this:
     ant -Duser.properties.file= jar (where you put the property "platforms.Default_JavaFX_Platform.home" in a .properties file)
  or ant -Dplatforms.Default_JavaFX_Platform.home= jar (where no properties file is used)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of Java from Oracle have JavaFx 2.x included:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

The stand-alone version of JavaFX for Java 6 appears to be available only for Windows (at least from the official download link).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid potential litigation by Oracle, the safe choice here would be to install OpenJDK, JDK's fully featured open-source build.

You can get it from https://adoptopenjdk.net/.